# Getting Duplicate while trying to read CSV file with Apache Common CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I have a class that try to read a CSV file using Apache Common CSV, so far my code is working fine except that am not getting the result am expecting.
My code is displaying a duplicate of the second column in the csv file as below:

```
support@gmail.com
google
google.com
support@gmail.com
google
tutorialspoint
info@tuto.com
google
```

**My CSV File**

```
Name,User Name,Password
google.com,support@gmail.com,google
tutorialspoint,info@tuto.com,google
```

i expect to get something like this:

```
google.com
support@gmail.com
google
tutorialspoint
info@tuto.com
google
```

**Here is my block that parses the csv using Apache CSV**

```
public List<String> readCSV(String[] fields) {
        // HERE WE START PROCESSING THE READ CSV CONTENTS
        List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        CSVParser csvFileParser = null;

        // HERE WE START PROCESSING
        if(fields!=null){
            //Create the CSVFormat object with the header mapping
            CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(FILE_HEADER_MAPPING);

            try {

                //Create a new list of student to be filled by CSV file data
                List<String> content=new ArrayList<String>();

                //initialize FileReader object
                fileReader = new FileReader(FilePath);

                //initialize CSVParser object
                csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);

                //Get a list of CSV file records
                List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords(); 

                //Read the CSV file records starting from the second record to skip the header
                for (int i = 1; i < csvRecords.size(); i++) {
                    CSVRecord record = csvRecords.get(i);
                    //Create a new student object and fill his data
                    for(int j=0; j<fields.length; j++){
                        content.add(record.get(fields[j]));
                    }
                    // Here we submit to contents
                    contents.addAll(content);
                    System.out.println(contents.size());
                } // end of loop
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fileReader.close();
                    csvFileParser.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
            // Here we return
            return contents;
        }
```

I cant just figure out what am missing here, any help will be welcomed.

Comment: Is your CSV a CSV or TSV? The contents you posted appear to be tab-separated... And do you mean to ignore the headers?

Comment: I have edited it, its comma separated value (CSV). I ignored the header while looping to display it

Comment: For someone else having this issue, make sure you aren't prematurely closing your reader before processing the parser. I found that doing this caused the headers to be duplicated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you're adding the String list `content` each iteration

```
                contents.addAll(content);
```

Either clear  `content` on each iteration or just change

```
                    content.add(record.get(fields[j]));
```

to

```
                    contents.add(record.get(fields[j]));
```

and remove the

```
                contents.addAll(content);
```

line

Comment: Thanks so much. I changed it to two dimensional array instead, it will be more easy to manipulate in future